# Numbers should be right-aligned. How to?

Tags: python-3.x, right-align

I am trying to make all numbers right-aligned, here is my code:

```
r=int(input('How many rows do you want?'))
while r<=0 :
    print('This value is not suitable')
    r=int(input('How many rows do you want?'))
c=int(input('How many columns do you want?'))
while c<=0 :
    print('This value is not suitable')
    c=int(input('How many columns do you want?'))

largest = (len(str(r**c)))
for i in range(1, r+1):
    for y in range(1, c+1):
        number = i**y
        tarp = ' ' * ((largest - len(str(number))))
        print(number, end = tarp) 
    print()
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by right-aligned? Your code is just printing some numbers in the command window, I don't think you can right-align there.

Comment: Assuming this prints into a console, what does it even mean to "right align" numbers? To some other text? To the edge of the console screen?

Comment: all numbers in rows should be right aligned

Comment: my task is - write code that will input two positive integers r and c and display a table with r rows and c columns, where the value of the mth number in the nth row is n^m